# How can I work with a large file in C#?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, iso

I want to work with a large .ISO file in C#. I want to manipulate it, adding and deleting files from it, and create a new iso from it. Ive tried the DiscUtils library but it seems I cant get it to work. When I load it (using standard C# functions) I always get a OutOfMemoryException. This is a 600MB ISO (more or less) and I have 2GB of RAM.

Im currently doing this:

```
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(fs);


                byte[] buffer = b.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);




                int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
                int sum = 0;
                while ((count = b.Read(buffer, (int)sum, (int)(buffer.Length - sum))) > 0)
                {
                    sum = sum + count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
                }
```

It throws the OutOfMemoryException at "byte[] buffer = b.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);". When I delete/add stuff to the ISO, I can then load it into parts or does it have to be the entire file?

UPDATE1: I limited the buffer with:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read,4096);
```

But still nothing.

How can I work with this?

Comment: In smaller chunks. You usually don't need all the data in the memory at the same time.

Comment: Do you want a large file in a `byte[]` or do you want to read the contents of a .ISO file?

Comment: You're probably getting OutOfMemoryException because you're reading too many bytes at a time. Using FileStream, you should be able to read a small chunk (e.g. 4096 bytes), write it to the new file, read the next chunk, and so on.

Comment: @dtb I read that the best way is in a array of bytes (byte[]) so I loaded it into that
ErenErsönmez How can I read small chunks but still check the MD5?

Comment: If all you want to do is calculate the MD5, then you don't need to load the bytes at all. Just pass the `Stream` to the MD5 instance.

Comment: @dtb Thats what I am currently doing; Later on, as I mentioned, I will be manipulating files inside of the .ISO such as listing, removing, adding, etc. MD5 is the least of my worries.

Comment: I already calculated it. Now I just have to be able to modify the ISO which is the main problem.

Comment: The thing about this was modifying the ISO......I could careless if I cant calculate the MD5.

Comment: I cant seem to be able to load it...Memory errors still exist.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle large files in C# is to use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) and process small chunks at a time. But it depends on your library if it can handle FileStreams if you can use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) are the way to deal efficiently with files that are too big to reside in memory.

Comment: Nicolas Repiquet, I also read about this and tested it out but I believe the DiscUtils library cannot use it so thats out of the question....